# tabbed content with dropdown menu with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to crate a page with tabbed content. Couple of tabs have dropdown menus. I am creating this with li without href. Highlighting the li elements when I hover on them is happening only in the first instance after loading of the page. After that the page is behaving differently - not rendering the highlighting on hovering. Can any body suggest any remedy?

the codes are as follows:
HTML:

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li data-content="first" class="tab-link">First Tab</li>
    <li class="submenu-container"> First Dropdown
        <ul class="dropdown">
            <li data-content="second" class="tab-link">Second Tab</li>
            <li data-content="third" class="tab-link">Third Tab</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="submenu-container"> Second Dropdown
        <ul class="dropdown">
            <li data-content="fourth" class="tab-link">Fourth Tab</li>
            <li data-content="fifth" class="tab-link">Fifth Tab</li>
            <li data-content="sixth" class="tab-link">Sixth Tab</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li data-content="seventh" class="tab-link">Seventh Tab</li>
</ul>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<div class="selected" id="first">Contents of First Tab</div>
<div class="hidden" id="second">Contents of Second Tab</div>
<div class="hidden" id="third">Contents of Third Tab</div>
<div class="hidden" id="fourth">Contents of Fourth Tab</div>
<div class="hidden" id="fifth">Contents of Fifth Tab</div>
<div class="hidden" id="sixth">Contents of Sixth Tab</div>
<div class="hidden" id="seventh">Contents of Seventh Tab</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    //$('li[data-content="first"').css({'background-color':'lightgrey'});    //This line keeps the first tab highlighted when the page is being loded 

    $(document).ready(function() {

    $('li[data-content="first"').css({'background-color':'lightgrey','margin-bottom' : '-2px'}); //This line keeps the first tab highlighted when the page is being loded 



    $('li').on('click', function(e) {

        //////first few lines control the change of color of the selected tab///////

        //removing the previous selected menu state
        $('li').css({'background-color':'#b2b2ff'});

         //is this element from the second level menu?
        if($(this).closest('ul').hasClass('dropdown')){
             $(this).parents('li').css({'background-color':'lightgrey' ,'margin-bottom' : '-2px'});


        //this is a parent element
        }else{
             $(this).css({'background-color':'lightgrey' ,'margin-bottom' : '-2px'});
        }

        /////////////code for controlling change of color of selected tab ends here ///////
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        if ($(this).hasClass('submenu-container')) { //prevents any action when any of the top level menus having submenus is clicked
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }

        if ($(this).parents().find('li').hasClass('submenu-container')){ //selects appropriate div element having content 
                                                                         //relevant to the menu selected    

            var data_content = $(this).attr('data-content');

                $('div').each(function(){
                        if($(this).attr('id') == data_content) {
                            $(this).addClass('selected');
                            }
                        else 
                            {
                            $(this).removeClass('selected');
                            $(this).addClass('hidden');
                        }

                    });

                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }

    }); //End $('li').on('click')

}); //End $(document).ready()
```

and the CSS is:

```
.tabs {
list-style-type: none;
margin-bottom: 0;
}

.tabs > li {
float: left;
margin: 1px;
height: 40px;
text-align: center;
line-height: 250%;
padding: 7px;
background-color: #b2b2ff;
}

.tabs > li:hover {
background-color:#e5e5ff;
}

.dropdown {
display: none;
}

.tabs >li:hover > ul.dropdown {
list-style-type: none;
top: 7px;
left: -47px;    
position: relative;
display: block;
}

.tabs >li:hover > ul > li {
background-color: #b2b2ff;
z-index: 100;
padding: 7px;
}

ul.dropdown > li:hover {
background-color:#e5e5ff;
}


div {
padding: 100px;
}

.hidden {

clear: both;
display: none;

}

.selected {
clear: both;
display: block;
margin-top: -20px;
padding-left: 50px;
z-index: 0;
background-color: lightgrey;
height: 500px;
}
```

Thanks everyone.

Comment: What browser/OS are you using?  I created a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WxNvJX) and it seems to be working fine in Chrome, Safari and Firefox on OSX.  

Or perhaps I'm missing something

Comment: I use chrome and windows....

Comment: I have just checked the codepen. The content is not changing on clicking new tabs ....

Answer (score 2):

Quick and dirty fix would be to set:

```
.tabs > li:hover {
    background-color:#e5e5ff!important;
}
```

Because on click you set inline background-color css with jQuery.

You can test it here https://jsfiddle.net/L3ead1u8/

**Update**

Also one more solution would be with jQuery like this

```
//removing the previous selected menu state
$('li').css({'background-color':''});
$(this).css({'background-color':'#b2b2ff'});
```

Test here https://jsfiddle.net/L3ead1u8/1/

Comment: I like the '!important' way. With that I can highlight the submenu as well - which, I think is a bit difficult with changing css from within jquery.